# Data from db into google charts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

New to Rails.  How can I export data from my database( I'm using Sqlite3) into a chart in rails?  I have 2 columns I would like to visualizes,  Timestamps and Decimal values.

I have seen plenty of examples on how to display data with Google Charts in rails, but never data from a db.

Any instruction or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guest you are using [googlecharts](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/) gem. In the page there are a lot of really basic examples. like this one:

```
Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20])
```

So, instead of put the numbers, yo can put your data like this

```
Gchart.line(:data => MyModel.pluck(:my_attribute))
```

where my_atributte is a column in the MyModel Object

this will create a link like this:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:AjI9R&cht=lc&chs=300x200&chxr=0,0,70

and you can use it as you want... maybe put in a img tag or whatever

Comment: Thanks.  Where does the pluck method come from?

Comment: in fact is from ActiveRecord [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Answer (score 1):

write a webservice which will return json data, use that to populate charts
look here http://pivotallabs.com/building-a-fast-lightweight-rest-service-with-rails-3/